# Is standalone [render-html] needed?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

There is a tag [render-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/render-html) with no usage guidance or description. It only has 19 questions.

The tag itself does not make sense when used independently. We should burninate it, or may be simple editing and removing it from those 19 questions would be faster?! I am happy to edit, but want to get the community's opinion before going forward.

To explicitly address the criteria:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

There is no description to begin with.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

First of all, there is no description. Secondly, the parent tag [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) completely overshadows it.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Not really. I'd rather search for html, than think of searching for render-html.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Maybe, it will only refer to the process of rendering html. But it still needs to be accompanied with other tags (mentioning the technology being used, for instance) for it to make sense.

Answer (score 6):

render-html is the name of a React Native component. It is not a synonym or subset of [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), nor is it intended to refer to the act of rendering HTML.

Questions tagged [render-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/render-html) that are referring to the component (and not the act of rendering HTML, for example) should ideally be tagged [react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native) as well, at the bare minimum.

Comment: Then a tag wiki is needed. Because the lack of it simply doesn't reflect the tag's meaning.

Comment: @CinCout: Absolutely.

Comment: @CinCout, I cleaned the tag, and added a small wiki for the tag. Let's wait a couple of weeks to see if the tag has become messy again, if it has, then we can rename it to [react-render-html].